# lookup field values in two fixed format file in unix - not working

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have 2 fixed length files input#1 & input#2. I want to match the rows based on the value in position 37-50 in both files (pos 37-50 will have same value in both files).

If any matching record is found then cut the value against company code & Invoice number from input file #1 (position 99 until end of line).

The cut string (from Input #1) need to be appended at the end of the record/line.

Below is the code I tried (not working) and the input files & desired output. Please provide your advice.

**Code:**

```
awk '
NR==FNR && NF>1 {
    v=substr($0,37,14);
#print substr($0,37,14)
    next
}
NR==FNR && ( /Company Code/ OR /Invoice Number/ ) {
    sub(/Company Code/,"",$0);
    sub(/Invoice Number/,"",$0);
    a[v]=$0;
print $0
    next
}
(substr($0,37,14) in a) {
    print $0 a[substr($0,99)]
}' Input1.txt input2.txt input3.txt
```

**End code**

**Input #1 beginning**  Start's with some white spaces

```
         612  1111111111201402120000       2     1  111  211 Due Date                             20140101                           
         612  1111111111201402120000       2     1  111  311 Company Code                         227                                
         612  1111111111201402120000       2     1  111  411 Item Code                            12                                 
         612  1111111111201402120000       2     1  111  511 Invoice Number                       2014010                            
         612  1111111111201402120000       2     2  111  611 Company Code                         214                                
         612  1111111111201402120000       2     2  111  711 Item Code                            20                                 
         612  1111111111201402120000       2     2  111  811 Invoice Number                       3014010                            
         612  1111111111201402120000       2     3  111  911 Due Date                             20140101                           
         612  1111111111201402120000       2     3  111  111 Invoice Number                       40140101                           
         612  1111111111201402120000       2     3  111  121 user code                            15563263636                        
         612  1111111111201402120000       2     3  111  131 Amount Due                           100000                             
         612  111111111120140212000078978982123444  111  141 Due Date                             20140101                             
         612  111111111120140212000078978982123444  111  151 Invoice Number                       50140101                             
         612  111111111120140212000078978982123444  111  161 Amount Due                          008000
```

**Input #1 End**

**Input #2 beginning**
input 2

```
         510       77432201111010000       2     1        1ChK          100111000001    121000248           123456789            20111101.510.77432.20001C                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     1        2INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20001D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     1        3INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20002D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     1        4INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20003D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     1        5INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20004D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     2        1ChK          200111000002    121000248           123456789            20111101.510.77432.20002C                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     2        2INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20005D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     2        3INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20006D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     2        4INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20007D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     2        5INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20008D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     3        1ChK          300111000003    121000248           123456789            20111101.510.77432.20003C                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     3        2INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20009D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     3        3INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20010D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     3        4INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20011D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     6        1ChK          600111000006    121000248           123456789            20111101.510.77432.20006C                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     6        2INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20021D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     6        3INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20022D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     6        4INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20023D                         
         510       77432201111010000       2     6        5INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20024D
```

**Input #2 end**

**Desired outout**
Desired output

```
         510       77432201111010000       2     1        1ChK          100111000001    121000248           123456789            20111101.510.77432.20001C   2272014010 (company & Inv # from input 1)                     
         510       77432201111010000       2     1        2INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20001D   2272014010                                            
         510       77432201111010000       2     1        3INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20002D   2272014010                                            
         510       77432201111010000       2     1        4INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20003D   (company & Inv # from input 1)                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     1        5INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20004D   (company & Inv # from input 1)                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     2        1ChK          200111000002    121000248           123456789            20111101.510.77432.20002C   (company & Inv # from input 1)                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     2        2INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20005D   (company & Inv # from input 1)                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     2        3INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20006D   (company & Inv # from input 1)                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     2        4INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20007D   (company & Inv # from input 1)                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     2        5INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20008D   (company & Inv # from input 1)                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     3        1ChK          300111000003    121000248           123456789            20111101.510.77432.20003C   (company & Inv # from input 1)                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     6        1ChK          600111000006    121000248           123456789            20111101.510.77432.20006C   <there is no matching record in input 1, this will be blank>                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     6        2INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20021D   <there is no matching record in input 1, this will be blank>                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     6        3INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20022D   <there is no matching record in input 1, this will be blank>                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     6        4INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20023D   <there is no matching record in input 1, this will be blank>                      
         510       77432201111010000       2     6        5INv                                                                   20111101.510.77432.20024D   <there is no matching record in input 1, this will be blank>
```

Comment: You say `pos 37-50 will have same value in both files`, do they look same to you in your sample data?

Comment: @jaypal, they are same values in both files. whitespace 2 whitespace 1.

Comment: It must be the formatting. I am getting diff. values in both files. Sorry about that.

Comment: It must be formatting issue. Is there a way I can attach my input files here?

Comment: You can put them on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @jaypal - I think the file's off by the first 4 spaces that SO uses for formatting code.  Try putting 4 spaces in front of both files.

Comment: @n0741337 & jaypal, yes they are off by 4 spaces as I did code formatting, didnt realize it messed up input data.

Comment: @jaypal, I lost formatting after copying data into pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your `awk` code.

Let's go through them step-by-step:

1. `NR==FNR && NF>1 {...;next}NR==FNR && ...` -->  the `next` will prevent the second *action* from being performed for all but the first *record*.
2. `NR==FNR && ( /Company Code/ OR /Invoice Number/ ) {` --> `OR` is not a valid `awk` statement, the *logical OR*  is done using `||` (like you use `&&` and not `AND`).
3. `print $0 a[substr($0,99)]` --> `a[substr($0,99)]` takes everything from the 99th position of the *record* in your 2nd input file to look up in your array, but your key is from 37-50.

We can fix them the follwing way:

1. Get rid of the `next` in the first *action* and limit the 3rd *action* to *records* from the 2nd input file.
2. Substitute `OR` with `||`.
3. Use `substr($0,37,14)` as key to lookup in `a` and `substr(...,99)` the result.

This results in the following code (removing your diagnostic `print` commands and the unused 3rd input file):

```
awk '
NR==FNR && NF>1 {
    v=substr($0,37,14);
}
NR==FNR && ( /Company Code/ || /Invoice Number/ ) {
    sub(/Company Code/,"",$0);
    sub(/Invoice Number/,"",$0);
    a[v]=$0;
    next
}
NR!=FNR && (substr($0,37,14) in a) {
    print $0 substr(a[substr($0,37,14)],99)
}' input1.txt input2.txt
```

Since your input was off I could not reproduce your desired output but I hope you can figure it out from here on.

Also, I shortened your code to the following version doing what I think you want it to do starting from the input given:

```
awk '
{key=substr($0,37,14)}
NR==FNR{
  if(/Company Code/||/Invoice Number/)array[key]=substr($0,98)
  next
}
(key in array){print $0,array[key]}
' input1.txt input2.txt
```

If you need adjustments/explanations, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this **(Untested)**:

```
awk '
NR==FNR && /Company Code/ {
    cc[$3,$4] = $NF;
    next;
}
NR==FNR && /Invoice Number/ {
    inv[$3,$4] = $NF;
    next;
}
NR==FNR {next}
{print $0 FS cc[$3,$4] inv[$3,$4]}' input1 input2
```

Comment: am afraid it says syntax error. I know you said untested.

Comment: it's somehow not producing any output.

Comment: the output contains all the records from input1. It's actually not extracting records with "Company code" && "Invoice number".

Comment: It's NOT working for me. The code just recreates the input#1. Thanks for your time.