# Turning multiple lines into one line based on common fields (group by)

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have fixed length file (sorted) and need to concatenate field from multiple rows based on key fields. The key fields are first two columns. The first 3 rows has white spaces at the beginning. The actual file does not have "spaces" word I have put that here to keep the formatting.

**Input file**

```
spaces2   001  111  111 Company Code         227                                
spaces2   001  111  111 Plan Code            012                                 
spaces2   001  111  111 Invoice Number       2014010                            
0000002     2  111  111 Company Code         214                                
0000002     2  111  111 Plan Code            20                                 
0000002     2  111  111 Invoice Number       3014010
```

**Desired output:**

```
spaces2   001  111  111 Company Code         227-12-2014010                                
0000002     2  111  111 Company Code         214-20-3014010
```

Could someone please suggest how to do this.

Comment: String concatenation in awk can be as simple as `$1 "-" $2 "-" $3`.  Are you having trouble getting there from [jaypal's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029463/lookup-field-values-in-two-fixed-format-file-in-unix-not-working)?

Comment: @n0741337, I couldnt get what I was looking for and the Jaypal's logic did'nt help for my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$ cat file
      2   001  111  111 Company Code         227
      2   001  111  111 Plan Code            012
      2   001  111  111 Invoice Number       2014010
0000002     2  111  111 Company Code         214
0000002     2  111  111 Plan Code            20
0000002     2  111  111 Invoice Number       3014010
```

```
$ awk '(($1,$2) in a){a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]"-"$NF;next}{gsub(/ *$/,"");a[$1,$2]=$0}END{for(x in a) print a[x]}' file
      2   001  111  111 Company Code         227-012-2014010
0000002     2  111  111 Company Code         214-20-3014010
```

<strike>Note that arrays in `awk` are associative so the order of output will be random. If order is important then it needs to be handled with additional code.</strike>

If order is critical for you then you can do something like:

```
awk '($1,$2) in seen {
    lines[i] = lines[i]"-"$NF; 
    next
}
{
    gsub(/ *$/,""); 
    seen[$1,$2]++; 
    lines[++i] = $0
}
END {
    for(line = 1; line <= length(lines); line++) {
        print lines[line]
    }
}' file
```

Explaination:

- `($1,$2) in seen`: This looks for first two fields in array seen. If it is present, it appends the last field to array line and `next` skips rest of the action.
- `{ .. }` - This code block gets executed for lines that are not in array seen. Typicall your first line will always enter here. So we use `gsub` to remove trailing space and populate the array `seen` and store that line in array `line`.
- In the `END` block, we iterate over the array `line` and print it. Since we use incremental index, the order is preserved. 
  Note: This expects your input data to be ordered

Comment: Terrific answer my friend

Comment: Note that OP said the file has "fixed length" lines. which means each line has trailing spaces. the output would be different in this case. also if remove the trailing lines then concatenate, better with `printf` to keep the length same.

Comment: Good point @Kent. I added a lazy `gsub` to remove the trailing space.

Comment: @jaypal, I'll implement your solution, I would be required to keep order in the output. Thanks

Comment: @user3353722 I added an alternate solution to keep data ordered. However, it expects your input data to be in the same order.

Comment: @jaypal, this one works perfect for my scenario. Thanks a lot and appreciate it.

Comment: @user3353722 You're welcome buddy. Sorry about your other question. May be you can shorten your data set and we can try it again later.

Comment: @jaypal, Could you please explain the logic.